# mysql XA commit

Tags: mysql, xa

While committing XA pending transactions on mysql restart I am getting the following the error. Please help me in resolving this error.

```
mysql> XA RECOVER CONVERT XID;
+----------+--------------+--------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| formatID | gtrid_length | bqual_length | data                                                                                           |
+----------+--------------+--------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  4871251 |           26 |           20 | 0xA223010095EDCC9A6369736861322C7365727665722C503130306369736861322C7365727665722C503130302C00 |
|  4871251 |           26 |           20 | 0xA123010095EDCC9A6369736861322C7365727665722C503130306369736861322C7365727665722C503130302C00 |
|  4871251 |           26 |           20 | 0xA023010095EDCC9A6369736861322C7365727665722C503130306369736861322C7365727665722C503130302C01 |


mysql> XA COMMIT 0x7023010095EDCC9A6369736861322C7365727665722C503130,0x306369736861322C7365727665722C503130302C00,4871251;
ERROR 1397 (XAE04): XAER_NOTA: Unknown XID

[root@db1 ~]# mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.20, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
[root@db1 ~]# uname -a
Linux db1 3.10.0-514.26.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jun 30 05:26:04 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[root@db1 ~]# cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.3 (Maipo)
```

Comment: I do not see where you got the gtrid part in the commit. It does not correspond to any of the 3 values returned by the recovery statement.

Comment: We have 77 similar rows. this is the one for which we have tried to commit.|  4871251 |           26 |           20 | 0x7023010095EDCC9A6369736861322C7365727665722C503130306369736861322C7365727665722C503130302C00 |

Comment: And it really didn't occur to you that you should put this data into the sample in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to you data, the `gtrid`'s length is 26, but the `gtrid` value in your commit (`7023010095EDCC9A6369736861322C7365727665722C503130`) has only 50 characters, so the actual length is only 25, not 26. Correspondingly, your `bqual` is longer. Your `gtrid` should be `7023010095EDCC9A6369736861322C7365727665722C50313030` and should adjust the `bqual` accordingly.